# Svelte: Second Instantiation of App Constructor Overwrites the First Instantiation, Props Going into Stores the Problem?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-3, svelte-store

Hello Sveltermeisters,

Problem:
I'm trying to initialize two instances of App on the same page. App is exposed as a global variable on the page in the main.js file like this:

```
//main.js
import App from './components/App.svelte'
window.App = App
```

And then initalizes two app instances in an html page

```html
<!–– index.html  ––> 
<button id="cta-button>CTA</button>
<button id="cta-button-2>CTA</button>

<!–– app.js is built and deployed as remote resource  ––> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://path.to/app.js"></script>
<script>
  const app = new App({
    target: document.querySelector('body'),
    props: {
      targetButtonIdToShowFormModal: "cta-button",
      iGetDroppedIntoAStore1: "some value",
      iGetDroppedIntoAStore2: "some value",
      iGetDroppedIntoAStore3: "some value"
    }
  })
  const app2 = new App({
    target: document.querySelector('body'),
    props: {
      targetButtonIdToShowFormModal: "cta-button-2",
      iGetDroppedIntoAStore1: "some different value",
      iGetDroppedIntoAStore2: "some different value",
      iGetDroppedIntoAStore3: "some different value"
    }
  })
</script>
```

Curious thing is: the props of the second app overwrite the props of the first, and the state of each app always stays in sync, regardless of which app is open.

My assertion: Since the props get dumped into stores, the second instance is overwriting the first. And since each app is referencing the same set of stores, their data always stays in sync.

Is this true?  If so, how can I design my stores so that their data stays separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a store instance for each `App` instance, you can use `context`  [`setContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#setContext) & [`getContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#getContext).

> Associates an arbitrary context object with the current component and
>   the specified key. The context is then available to children of the
>   component (including slotted content) with getContext.
>
> ---
>
> **Context is not inherently reactive. If you need reactive values in
>   context then you can pass a store into context, which will be
>   reactive.**

([Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-margulis-wqz50?fontsize=14))

Comment: Fantastic.  Will need to wrap my head around the context api.  Will report back when I rewrite some of the stores.  Thank you!

Comment: This code worked.  Thank you.  This may be substance for another stack overflow question, but I'm curious how you might use this with derived stores?